# Callback routes with expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Please, i need to figure out why the external callback(defined in a diff file) assigned to a route like

```
app.get('/list', routes.list);
```

it's working and if I define

```
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/list', routes.list);
```

the callback stops to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should apply routes for your application, for example

```
var routes = {
  list: function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './public', 'index.html'));
  }
};

// app.get('/list', routes.list);
router.get('/list', routes.list);

// apply the routes to our application
app.use('/', router);

app.listen(3000);
```